# Error while using the pandas_datareader package

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a basic project where I grab some data from Morningstar or Google Finance, but when I import the package according to the usage instructions on GitHub and run Python in Pycharm, it returns the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'is_list_like'
```

What should I do? Obviously, I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BEFORE** you `import pandas_datareader`, run this:

```
pd.core.common.is_list_like = pd.api.types.is_list_like
```

where pd stands for your pandas import.

Let me know if this works :)